# Difference in work done for different directions of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, work

If I am lifting a weight, i.e, a rectangular object of 200kgs from one end off the ground(around 3 inches above the ground) having a dimension of 48 inches by 30 inches. How much weight am I lifting if I compare the same with a deadlift where I lift weight parallel to the ground?

To suffice, I want to know if I am lifting that object from one end how much weight is being lifted if I want to put it equivalent to a deadlift which I do using a bar which also approximately placed in the same position above the ground as this object is?

Comment: So you mean if you're leaning forward and thus lifting it in an angle vs lifting it straight upwards? First of all i think you mean that you deadlift and lift it "normal" to the ground. Seondly, have you thought about calculating the work done? F*distance moved = W?

Comment: You aren't doing work when you don't move the body to a higher potential. I don't know what deadlifts are, but a quick google search tells me that it isn't well-described by 'lifting weight parallel to the ground'. Perhaps you could clarify that definition?

Comment: @DakkVader, I am lifting the weight which is evenly spread across the body. And point of contact of this body on the ground acts as a `fulcrum` and I thereby lift the weight at 45 degree angle. How much weight am I lifting as compared to when I lift the weight straight up from the ground(not overhead) only upto the my thighs(deadlift).

Comment: @Chair Deadlift is when you bend your knees and tilt your back making an almost 90 degree angle over the bar and thereafter lifting it. Hope that explains it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the weight of the object is uniformly distributed across the object, then you are lifting half the weight, 100kg, and the other half is supported by the ground.

Another way to look at this is to consider the object as a lever with all its weight at the centre. When you lift one end 3 inches, the centre lifts 1.5 inches. The work you are doing = force $\times$ distance, and to lift the 200kg weight 1.5 inches, you are moving half the weight (100kg) by twice the distance (3 inches).

> To suffice, I want to know if I am lifting that object from one end
>   how much weight is being lifted if I want to put it equivalent to a
>   deadlift which I do using a bar which also approximately placed in the
>   same position above the ground as this object is?

Sorry, I don't know much about weightlifting, and I can't figure out exactly what you are asking there.

Comment: Let me clarify, the weight is evenly distributed across the object and when I lift the object off the ground making a 45 degree angle then as you told, half the weight is supported by the ground. I guess, the point of the object which is supported on the ground acts as a `fulcrum` and if I lift the weight off the ground about 48 inches away from the fulcrum making an angle of 45 degrees, ow much weight am I lifting? I am sorry, I dont know about formula to calculate it, could you help me calculate that?